# drupal block listing articles with custom scrollbar

Tags: drupal, scroll, drupal-blocks

I want to create a block listing some articles and I want to add a custom scrollbar to that box. So it shows 3 article teasers and then it scrolls but scrollbar is custom design.How can I do that?Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create custom scrollbars, you need webkit.

Webkit: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

See the examples and read the documentation on how to do this.

In order to pull your 3 articles, you can use the views modules and create a block views.
The views module is hard to explain but you will manage if you take the time to read the doc and experiment with it.

Views: http://drupal.org/project/views